# React-Native Image tag defaultSource point to in memory image data?

Tags: android, react-native

Docs say:

```
defaultSource

A static image to display while loading the image source.

    uri - a string representing the resource identifier for the image, which should be either a local file path or the name of a static image resource (which should be wrapped in the require('./path/to/image.png') function).
    width, height - can be specified if known at build time, in which case these will be used to set the default <Image/> component dimensions.
    scale - used to indicate the scale factor of the image. Defaults to 1.0 if unspecified, meaning that one image pixel equates to one display point / DIP.
    number - Opaque type returned by something like require('./image.jpg').
```

file reference only. How can I reference an in memory image data like the sample code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob#download-example--fetch-files-that-needs-authorization-token

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/images/img1.png', {
    Authorization : 'Bearer access-token...',
    // more headers  .. 
  })
  // when response status code is 200 
  .then((res) => {
    // the conversion is done in native code 
    let base64Str = res.base64()
    // the following conversions are done in js, it's SYNC 
    let text = res.text()
    let json = res.json()

  })
  // Status code is not 200 
  .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
    // error handling 
  })
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9880

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible.

The [defaultSource](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#defaultsource) property only accepts two different types:

1. A number, which is returned by `require('./image.jpg')`
2. An object with this shape: `{uri: string, width: number, height: number, scale: number}`. The `uri` field is a string to point to images from native side.